# Minimum number of letters

Tags: regular-languages, regular-expressions, pushdown-automata

I have an assignment that I have to do and the question is

> Draw a DPDA that accepts the language L = {ba(bb)^(n+1)a^(n – 1) |n > 1}.

Im not looking for the answer but rather some direction. I would like to understand the 'n' powers.

Currently my understanding of the above language is that it will start with ba (obviously) Then it will have (bb) however this is where I am confused....

The last part says n > 1 does that mean that n+1 will have a min value of 3 meaning the language will always start with abbbbbbb(bb)* or does n > 1 mean at least 1 i.e. n+1 min value is 2?

Again please dont give me the solution to the DPDA as I would like to figure that out on my own.

Thanks
Jacques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

n>1 means that minimum n value is 2.

(bb)^n means bb repeated n times, i.e. if n=2, then it's bbbb.

With n=2, it's "ba bbbbbb a" (I added spaces only for clarity).

With n=3, it's "ba bbbbbbbb aa" - as you see, teacher used n to regulate size of the first and the second repetition in sync.

Comment: Please also mark it as accepted answer (checkmark below the counter at left) to clear it from the list of unanswered questions